# Can NetNestOperator take a non pre-defined number of iterations?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'd like to `Nest` a particular `NetChain` inside a larger `NetGraph` for a random number of iterations per round or batch. Is this possible?
Here are my (so far fruitless) attempts:

First, we define a dummy `NetChain` and illustrate how to `Nest` it for a fixed number of iterations using a few methods:

```
nc = NetInitialize[NetChain[{2, Ramp}, "Input" -> 2]];
nested[1] = NetNestOperator[nc, 3];
nested[2] = FunctionLayer[Nest[nc, #, 3] &];
nested[3] = 
  NetTake[NetGraph[FunctionLayer[NestList[nc, #, 3] &]], 
   3*Information[nc, "LayersCount"]];
nested[4] = 
  CompiledLayer[
   FunctionCompile[
    Function[Typed[arg, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]], 
     Nest[Typed[
       KernelFunction[
        nc], {TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]} -> 
        TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]], arg, 3]]]];

(*Show Equivalence*)
Through[(nested /@ Range[4])[{0.3, 0.2}]]
SameQ @@ %

Out[1]= {{0.369132, 0.}, {0.369132, 0.}, {0.369132, 0.}, {0.369132, 0.}}
Out[2]= True
```

From these, the last would require the additional definition of `gradientfunc` to be usable in `NetTrain`, so likely less appealing, and the third perhaps gives a hint on how this can be achieved semi-manually.

Naively, I hoped this syntax would allow for a second input port for the second method:

```
FunctionLayer[Function[{in, iter}, Nest[nc, in, iter]]]

During evaluation of In[3]:= FunctionLayer::compilerr: Cannot interpret Nest[NetChain[<2>], #1, #2] & as a network.
Out[3]= $Failed
```

If this (or similar) worked, then one could attach a `RandomArrayLayer` as the second input, e.g. something like this:

```
ra=RandomArrayLayer[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{4,6}],"Output"->"Integer"];
ra[]

Out[4]= 6
```

#### EDIT 01:

I guess one could do the following, where we're appending the random integer as the last entry of the input array (since `CompiledLayer` expects a single input):

```
nested[5] = 
  CompiledLayer[
   FunctionCompile[
    Function[Typed[arg, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]], 
     Nest[Typed[
       KernelFunction[
        nc], {TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]} -> 
        TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]], Most[arg], 
      Round[Last[arg]]]]]];

nested[5][{0.3, 0.2, 4}]
nested[5][{0.3, 0.2, 5}]
nested[5][{0.3, 0.2, 6}]

Out[5]= {0.336348, 0.}
Out[6]= {0.306477, 0.}
Out[7]= {0.279258, 0.}
```

But then I'm not sure how to compute `gradientfunc`..

#### EDIT 02:

The accepted answer from @xslittlegrass does the trick very nicely! FWIW, much of that coded can be simplified as follows:

```
randomNesting = NetChain[{
   FunctionLayer[NestList[nc, #, 9] &],
   FunctionLayer[RandomChoice]
   }]
```

We can use a particularly simple `nc` (a simple rotation matrix by 45°) to demonstrate this

```
nc = NetChain[{LinearLayer[2, "Weights" -> RotationMatrix[π/4.], 
     "Biases" -> None]}, "Input" -> 2];
Table[randomNesting[{0.3, 0.2}], 4]
```

`{{-0.2, 0.3}, {-0.3, -0.2}, {-0.3, -0.2}, {-0.3, -0.2}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way to achieve this is to compute the all the nested results and then pick the correct one according the to random number, something like this

```
maxIteration = 10;
NestList[f, a, maxIter][[RandomInteger[{1, maxIter}]]]
```

This can be done by sharing the weights across all the repeated NetChain.

```
layers = Flatten@{
    Table["nc" <> ToString[i] -> nc, {i, 1, maxIter}],
    "cat" -> CatenateLayer[], 
    "reshape" -> ReshapeLayer[{maxIter, 2}],
    "rand" -> 
     RandomArrayLayer[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, maxIter}], 
      "Output" -> {1}],
    "part" -> ExtractLayer[]
    };

connections = Flatten@{
    Rule @@@ 
     Partition[Table["nc" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, maxIter}], 2, 1],
    Table["nc" <> ToString[i] -> "cat", {i, 1, maxIter}],
    "rand" -> NetPort["part", "Position"],
    "cat" -> "reshape" -> "part"
    };

net = NetInitialize@NetGraph[layers, connections]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks! FWIW, all of these can be achieved simply using `FunctionLayer` as follows: `NetChain[{
  FunctionLayer[NestList[nc, #, 9] &],
  FunctionLayer[RandomChoice]
  }]`. I'll edit my question demonstrating this so it's easier for others to find it in the future!

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides That's nice! Good to know.